# Issues with Rough edges using Grab brush in Sculpting mode

Tags: sculpting

I am using Blender 3.6 in sculpt mode and I'm having issues with the Grab brush tool.
I'm expecting an Even grab outcome but the outcome is always JAGGED/SPIKY, making it appear that not all vertices within the brush cursor are being grabbed.
[image]

Attached is a download link with a sphere that exibhits the same issue whilst using a Grab brush:
[image]

Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Hello, maybe you have a texture selected? Or please share your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I can think of:

### Apply scale

Bad scales are probably not the main cause here, but it can definitely make things worse.
In object mode, select your object, hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Apply Scale.

### Auto masking

[image]

Depending on the object, this can lead to unexpected results.

In your case, it treats the bumpy surface of your mesh as a succession of cavities to leave untouched, hence it lets you move some vertices and not so much the others.
You could either tweak the cavity detection values if you want to use it, or just disable it.

### Brush Texture

You have a texture loaded in your brush:

[image]

Click the <kbd>X</kbd> icon next to the texture to remove it.

### Brush Falloff

You have a different falloff than the default "Smooth" in your brush, maybe a custom one like so:

[image]

Set it back to smooth.

### Something else in the brush

In doubt, just reset the brush from the Viewport's Sidebar > Tool tab > Brushes Panel > <kbd>⌄</kbd> button > Reset Brush:

[image]

Comment: I tried the above but it didn't help, not sure why. However when i create a new .blend file from scratch, the issue goes away. I still have no clue what is the cause, but i'll keep your suggestions in case i face similar future issues. Thank you all for the replies

Comment: Maybe post your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and then [edit] your question to add the download link and we could check what's going on.

Comment: I've edited my question with a .blend file for help

Comment: Found the issue, turns out it was the automasking. See my answer edit 

Comment: THANK YOU!  It would have took me a million years to figure that out myself.